# Prevent autofocus of contents in Material UI's date input

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, input, material-ui

i am trying to figure out how to prevent the contents of Material UI's date input from being automatically focused when inputing characters. For some reason, the focus is on whichever field I am typing in. For example if I am typing the year portion of the date, all four digits will be highlighted which means when I backspace, even if I mean to just clear one digit, all digits would be cleared. Please see image below this paragraph of what I mean.

[image]

Like I said, I think that behavior of clearing all digits with a single backspace is due to all digits of whichever current portion of the date being selected all at one.

I have tried to use the css ways like setting userSelect to 'none' for the input, as well as setting tabIndex to -1. That doesn't seem to do anything. Please see my code below:

```
<TextField
  tabindex="-1"
            className={`${classes.formInput} ${classes.dateInput}`}
            classes={{ root: classes.dateInput}}
            value={date}
            name="date"
            onChange={e => setFormField(e.target.getAttribute('name'), e.target.value)}
            type="date"
            required
            label="Date"
            variant="standard" />
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not possible to change this since the `TextField` is build on top of the native `input` element. If you take a look at the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) about the native input you will see that this is currently the only way to input on `type="date"`

You can use the [DatePicker](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#basic-usage) from the MUI library this input does allow you to "backspace".

I hope this helps you!